# js object passed to a function becomes a string

Tags: javascript

`I have written a js function to traverse a javascript object and output it's contents with console.log().  It recursively calls itself when a property that is an object is encountered.  The problem is in the recursive loops, the passed in property doesn't show any child properties.

Take the sample below (also at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeljeljel/6XfX8/)), once the jsObject.payload is passed into the recursive call, 'payload' appears to revert to a simple string object.

```
var EnumerateObject = function(object, path) {
    if (!path) path = '';

    for (var property in object) {
        if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            if (typeof object[property] === "object") EnumerateObject(property, path + '.' + property);
            else console.log(path + '.' + property + '=' + typeof property);
        }
    }
}

var json = '{"success": true, "error": "", "payload": { "fetch": "1", "xml": "<xml />" }}';
var jsObject = $.parseJSON(json);

EnumerateObject(jsObject);
```

I know I am missing something subtle here, but I am not sure why my passed in 'property' to the 'object' parameter suddenly becomes a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

property is a string containing the value "payload".

`object[property]` is `{'fetch':'1', 'xml':.... }`

Answer (score 2):

Object keys are always strings.  So when you do `typeof property` then `property` is the key not the value.  You probably mean to do `typeof object[property]`.

So they are NOT being converted to strings, you were just getting the type of the wrong object.

Answer (score 1):

here is the fixed solution:

```
var EnumerateObject = function(jsonObject, path) {
    if (!path) path = '';

    for (var prop in jsonObject) {
        if (jsonObject.hasOwnProperty(prop )) {

            if (typeof(jsonObject[prop ]) === "object") EnumerateObject(jsonObject[prop ], path + '.' + prop );
            else console.log(path + '.' + prop + '=' + typeof prop );
        }
    }
}

var json = '{"success": true, "error": "", "payload": { "fetch": "1", "xml": "<xml />" }}';
var jsObject = $.parseJSON(json);

console.log(typeof(jsObject["payload"]));
EnumerateObject(jsObject);
```

please remove the use of reserverd keywords like object.. IE might crap out..